# Communicating between a Chrome extension popup and an iFrame embedded in that popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

I have an iFrame embedded in my Chrome extension popup which displays a webpage that I am in control of. I am able to send data from the iFrame to the Chrome popup script using sendMessage from my embedded website and onMessageExternal from my popup script, but I would also like to send data the other way around (such as the extension id - I can’t access this value within an iframe).

I’ve read about methods such as using the window.postMessage() function available in HTML5, and have investigated the method discussed [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication), although I am not sure the second method would work in the context I intend to use it in. If I were to use postMessage, I would not be able to confirm that the message was sent by my extension as there is no domain for me to check against unless I hardcoded my plugin id in, which I would like to avoid.

Is there another method of doing what I am trying to do, or would postMessage be the best way? I want to avoid query strings to make it somewhat more difficult to send an illegitimate request to my webpage. I’m not doing anything with sensitive data, I’m just using the data to make changes to the behaviour of the webpage based on whether it is running in an extension or running natively in the browser, and using the extension id for logging purposes.

Comment: What's wrong with hardcoding the id? It will never change once the extension is in webstore. Anyway, since you already can communicate it means you have "externally_connectable" in manifest.json so all you need is to switch to [long-lived `port` messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect).

Comment: Hardcoding the id could work, and come to think of it, I may well end up doing this (although I will still need messaging for some other pieces of information).I don’t remember why, but I was under the impression that lond-lived connections would not work in this situation. Perhaps I misread something. I will give this a try, else I will try postMessage, which supposedly will send the extension id as the sending domain, according to another post I read. If this is the case, I can simply hard code the id to confirm the source.